# Is the following inside of outside the Nyquist curve?

Tags: control-theory

Consider the following Nyquist plot,

[image: Nyqvist plot]

Is the green dot outside it or inside it? To me this would be outside the interior of the plot. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The green dot lies inside the Nyquist plot. In fact, the green dot is encircled **twice** in the clockwise direction.
If you are going to perfrom stability analysis, be sure to note if you made a plot of $$1+G(s)H(s)$$ or $$G(s)H(s)$$ where $\left[1+G(s)H(s)\right]$ is the system characteristic equation.